# js refresh page while passing variable in yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I am trying to refresh the page while pass an array from an onclick button.
Since I am using yii, posting isn't an option, and setting a session variable wasn't working.  Any ideas would help.  Thank you

```
<a style="width:100%;" onclick="my_picks_reset()" id="my_picks_reset">Reset</a>     

<script>
$(function() {
    /*set var picks = array of TBA and reset th my_picks div*/
    $("#my_picks_reset").click(function() {
        var my_picks = ['TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA','TBA'];
        var url = document.URL;
        $(location).attr('href',url,'my_picks',my_picks);
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: where do you want to pass the array to? to back-end?

Comment: The url is http://localhost/index.php/ticket/update/1.  So i would think that i would like to pass it to the actionUpdate. (seen below)

    public function actionUpdate($id)
 {
  $model=$this->loadModel($id);

  if(isset($_POST['Picks']))
  {
   $model->attributes=$_POST['Picks'];
   if($model->save())
  $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->ID));
  }

  $this->render('update',array(
   'model'=>$model,
  ));
 }

Comment: Sorry, that didn't past well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your comments that you're expecting `POST` request. Changing location of the page will give you `GET` request. So you have two options here:

1) Continue using location and read the the values from `$_GET` variable.
If you decide to use this option your need loop through `my_picks` array and construct the query string that would look like that:
`?my_picks[]=arrayValue1&my_picks[]=arrayValue2...` and do `location.assign(currentLocation + composedQueryString)`
2) The second better solution is to use $.ajax() to send values with post method.

Comment: Thank you.  It took me some time to understand, but you were correct.